# Import my cythonized package in python

Tags: python, numpy, cython, distutils

I have a script_function_cython.pyx file containing a single function:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc as misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def my_function(img, kernel):

    assert kernel.shape==(3, 3)

    res = np.zeros(img.shape)

    for i in range(1, img.shape[0]-1):
        for j in range(1, img.shape[1]-1):

            res[i, j] = np.sum(np.array([[img[i-1, j-1], img[i-1, j], img[i-1, j+1]],
                                 [img[i, j-1], img[i, j], img[i, j+1]],
                                [img[i+1, j], img[i+1, j], img[i+1, j+1]]])*kernel)

    return res






if __name__ == '__main__':

    kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1], [-1, 3, -1], [-1, -1, -1]])
    img = misc.face()[:256, :256, 0]
    res = my_function(img, kernel)

    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(res, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

I have thus created a setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize('script_function_cython.pyx'),  
)
```

Then, I compile it:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

And install it:

```
python setup.py install
```

However, when I try to further import it,

```
import script_function_cython
```

I get:

```
ImportError: No module named script_function_cython
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the `--inplace` build there is no need for install. You'll need to import from project directory though.

```
python setup.py build --inplace
python -c 'import script_function_cython'
```

should raise no error.

Comment: I would like to import my script_function_cython in another python script, not within the command line. And your two lines raise the same import error.

Comment: I just tested that it works, so I would need more info.

Can you give the output of `ls -lh` in the directory where both 'script_function_cython.pyx' and 'setup.py' are located?

The command-line test I gave you is a check that the Python interpreter can load the module, that is all. It will search for it in the same way as an actual program would.

Comment: The problem came from the fact that the .so file was located in a build folder , while I was convinced it was generated in the same folder with setup.py and script_function_cython.pyx.

Comment: `--inplace` should place the `.so` file in the current directory. If that is not the case, there is still a problem. `python setup.py install` will anyway do a regular build on top of that and install the extension.